# Vue Increase and decrease value once (replacing buttons)

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I made a component that allows me to add a point for each user only once after button click. I would like to additionally enable the undo of an added point (decreasing the value by 1). When I add a point, I want the button to turn red and change the text to "Delete point".
This should be similar to marking the answers as helpful the stackoverflow (but without a negative point).
I used **v-if="user.title !== 'Jason Oner'"** to disable adding points for this user.
I have no idea how to solve this problem in this case.

[Demo code](https://codepen.io/noobmaster2137/pen/KKNrqPO)

**HTML:**

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-card
      class="mx-auto"
      max-width="900"
    >
  
      <v-list>
  
        <v-list-item
          v-for="user in users"
          :key="user.title"
        >
          <v-list-item-avatar>
            <v-img
              :alt="`${user.title} avatar`"
              :src="user.avatar"
            ></v-img>
          </v-list-item-avatar>
  
          <v-list-item-content>
            <v-list-item-title v-text="user.title"></v-list-item-title>
            <div class="points" v-text="user.points"></div>
          </v-list-item-content>
  
          <v-list-item-icon>
            <v-btn 
              v-if="user.title !== 'Jason Oner'"
              color="primary"
              @click.once="user.points++"
            >
              <v-icon left>
                mdi-plus
              </v-icon>
              Add point
            </v-btn>
          </v-list-item-icon>
        </v-list-item>
      </v-list>

    </v-card>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: () => ({
    users: [
      {
        avatar: 'https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/lists/1.jpg',
        title: 'Jason Oner',
        points: 5,
      },
      {
        avatar: 'https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/lists/2.jpg',
        title: 'Mike Carlson',
        points: 10,
      },
      {
        avatar: 'https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/lists/3.jpg',
        title: 'Cindy Baker',
        points: 15,
      },
      {
        avatar: 'https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/lists/4.jpg',
        title: 'Ali Connors',
        points: 20,
      },
    ],
  }),
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see if this helps
[Codepen Demo](https://codepen.io/manojkmishra/pen/abBPZWp)

HTML:

```
<div id="app">
<v-app id="inspire">
<v-card  class="mx-auto"  max-width="900">
    <v-list>
      <v-list-item  v-for="(user,index) in users" :key="user.title">
      <v-list-item-avatar>
        <v-img :alt="`${user.title} avatar`"  :src="user.avatar"></v-img>
      </v-list-item-avatar>
      <v-list-item-content>
        <v-list-item-title v-text="user.title"></v-list-item-title>
        <div class="points" v-text="user.points"></div>
      </v-list-item-content>
      <v-list-item-icon>
        <div v-if="user.add">
          <v-btn  v-if="user.title !== 'Jason Oner'" color="primary" @click="aab(index)">
            <v-icon left> mdi-plus </v-icon> Add point
          </v-btn>
        </div>
        <div v-else>
          <v-btn  v-if="user.title !== 'Jason Oner'" color="error" @click="aab(index)">
            <v-icon left> mdi-plus </v-icon> Del point
          </v-btn>
        </div>
      </v-list-item-icon>
    </v-list-item>
  </v-list>

 </v-card>
 </v-app>
 </div>
```

JS:

```
new Vue({
el: '#app',
vuetify: new Vuetify(),
methods:{
aab(ii)
{   let uu=this.users[ii];
  if(uu.add) {   uu.points++;uu.add=false;uu.sub=true  }
  else{ uu.points--; uu.add=true;uu.sub=false}
}
},

data: () => ({
users: [
  {
    avatar: 'https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/lists/1.jpg',
    title: 'Jason Oner',
    points: 5,add:true,sub:false,
  },
  {
    avatar: 'https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/lists/2.jpg',
    title: 'Mike Carlson',
    points: 10,add:true,sub:false,
  },
  {
    avatar: 'https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/lists/3.jpg',
    title: 'Cindy Baker',
    points: 15,add:true,sub:false,
  },
  {
    avatar: 'https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/lists/4.jpg',
    title: 'Ali Connors',
    points: 20,add:true,sub:false,
  },
],
}),
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You would have to store somewhere who the current user (you) have upvoted. Normally this is would be in your case on a user object in the users array. eg

```js
{
    avatar: 'https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/lists/4.jpg',
    title: 'Ali Connors',
    points: 20,
    // alternatives:
    haveIGivenPoint: false,
    usersGivenPoints: [1, 5, 2] // Represents user ids that has given points
    points: [1, 5, 2] // Instead of points above as a number, you could count users ids who has given points
    // etc... It's up to you how to save this state
},
```

When you have chosen a way to store what you have voted for, you need to use this info on the button:

```html
<v-list-item-icon>
    <v-btn 
        v-if="!user.haveIGivenPoint"
        color="primary"
        @click.once="user.points++"
    >
        <v-icon left>
            mdi-plus
        </v-icon>
        Add point
    </v-btn>
    <v-btn 
        v-else
        color="red"
        @click.once="user.points--"
    >
        <v-icon left>
            mdi-minus
        </v-icon>
        Undo point
    </v-btn>
</v-list-item-icon>
```